# Understanding more complex examples of descendant selectors

Tags: html, css

I somewhat understand descendant selectors, but the more complex examples are giving me trouble. For example:

```
#content .alternative p
```

Should this rule apply to p elements that are descendants of elements E, where E are :

- descendants of element `#conten`t and
- are also members of class `.alternative`

Or should rule apply to `p` elements that are:

- descendants of element `#content`
- and are also members of class `.alternative`?

How about the following rule?

```
#content .alternative .alternative1 p
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right most component of the selector is the part that actually picks the element. A space is a descendant selector. If there isn't a space then the selectors all apply to one element.

```
#content .alternative p
```

p element contained in an element of class alternative contained in an element of id content.

```
#content .alternative .alternative1 p
```

p element contained in an element of class alternative1 contained in an element of class alternative contained in an element of id content.

```
#content p.alternative.alternative1
```

p element of class alternative1 and of class alternative contained in an element of id content.

Answer (score 7):

About the first question: applies to **p** elements that are: 
descendants of element #content *and also descendants* of elements with class .alternative

The second one is the same, just with an extra level of depth.

Check [this link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/) for more info on selectors

Comment: also .alternative has to be a descendant of #content

Answer (score 1):

Each section of the specifier separated by a space refers to a separate node in the document.  So its the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the correct description. Your second interpretation would be written in CSS as:

```
#content p.alternative
```

Since the `.alternative` is attached to the `p` in that version, it's a qualifier rather than specifying a descendent. If you instead write it as

```
#content p .alternative
```

it would mean elements of class `.alternative` that are descendents of `p` elements that are descendents of the `#content` element.